# Why vue.js component is not showing fetched data on the first try?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I successfully get data from an external js file (long Json process, exports promise function), but the data it's not been added to the component on the first try. I have to enter in a different component and then when returning the data is shown.

I have tried using the beforeCreate() method, but it hasn't help, the condole.log(data) shows the information, but the component is not.

```
<template>
   <div class="roomsBar">
      <div class="roomsArea">
          <li v-for="building in allBuildings" :key="building">
              <a v-on:click="clicked(building)">{{building}}</a>
      </li>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import {menuData as menuData} from '../controllers/navigation.js';

export default {
    name: 'Buildings',
    data() {
        return {
        allBuildings: window.menu
    }
    },
    methods: {
    clicked: function(item){
        this.$router.push({ path: '/navigation/'+item })
    }
    },
    beforeCreate() {
    window.menu = [];
    menuData().then((data) => {   // Recover the data from 'Navigation.js'
        console.log(data);
            for (const element of data) { // Filter data and only add building to the menu
        window.menu.push(element.building);
    }
    console.log(window.menu);
    });
    }
}
</script>


<style scoped>
    .roomsBar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #42b983;
    }
</style>
```

I need that the data to be showed on the first try.

I'm actually new in vue by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because Vue cannot track when `window.menu` changed, and is therefore unable to re-render as such.

Your entire use of `window` for this is dubious at best. Consider the following:

```js
let menuData = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      return resolve([{
          name: 'test'
        },
        {
          name: 'test 2'
        }
      ]);
    }, 100);
  });
}

let component = Vue.component('test', {
  name: 'Buildings',
  template: '<ul><li v-for="item in allBuildings">{{item.name}}</li></ul>',
  data: () => ({

    allBuildings: []
  }),
  beforeCreate() {
    menuData().then((data) => {
      this.$set(this.$data, 'allBuildings', data);
    });
  }
});

let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <test></test>
</div>
```

With this small rewrite, we achieved multiple things:

- you no longer depend on an array stored outside of this item (I.e. `window`), preferring to leverage a property of your object itself
- Vue now clearly knows when the array changes, as we are calling `$set`
- the link between the two is now explicit

More information about `$set`/`Vue.set` is available on the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) and is the main way to store and update reactive data.

---

Regarding the `for` loop and filtering, if you are never going to refresh this component's data, it is perfectly fine to keep `push`ing to the array, like so:

```
menuData().then((data) => {
  for (const element of data) {
    this.$data.allBuildings.push(element);
  }
});
```

Vue.js directly supports [most array mutation methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) straight on the data object itself; if you find yourself in the case where you need to filter an array, making use of those or building the array separately then `$set`ting it would also work.

Comment: I think that i get what you wrote, but vue trows an error `Property or method "allBuildings" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

And a `Avoid adding reactive properties to a Vue instance or its root $data at runtime - declare it upfront in the data option.`

Also, the reason i sue a `for` it's because i need to filter the data, so how can ido this using the `$set`?

Comment: @MauricioAndrés apologies. I jotted that answer down from mobile then went straight to bed - back on it now, and I'll address the `for` part for you :-)

Comment: There. Edited, code is now a snippet (something I could not do from my phone), and it works

Comment: Awesome, thanks now my component works as expected, huge thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You should initialize allBuildings with empty array, 
not with non-existing object which causes the error.

```
export default {
  name: 'Buildings',
  data() {
    return {
      allBuildings: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicked: function(item){
      this.$router.push({ path: '/navigation/'+item })
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    window.menu = [];
    menuData().then((data) => {
      for (const element of data) {
        window.menu.push(element.building);
      }

      this.allBuildings = window.menu;
    });
  }
}
```